# Add claims to Role

Tags: asp.net-identity, roles, claims-based-identity, claims

I want to add claims to each role in my project and then validate permission, not the whole role.
I have read the article http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims and see the lines:

```
await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.Permission, "projects.view"));
await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.Permission, "projects.create"));
await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.Permission, "projects.update"));
```

I created the following role manager:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

and register it in startup:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

then get it:

```
    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
```

but RoleManager does not have a method AddClaimAsync. How to add claims to role?

Comment: Is your project asp.net core? If so, you may want to add the asp.net-core tag to your question.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, oh, it works only for Core...

Comment: Here's an article you may find interesting: https://brechtvn.wordpress.com/2016/10/19/using-asp-net-identity-role-claims-without-net-core/

Comment: Does the store you pass to the `ApplicationRoleManager` *constructor* implement `IRoleClaimStore`? Becaues the [RoleManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/RoleManager.cs#L451) supports `AddClaimAsync` only if it does.